# Vs code live server Cannot get error message

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, static, liveserver

I'm currently developing a simple static web page with only HTML.
I'm using  tags with href to link to different pages and the VS code live server used to work when I inserted a link like page1.html it would send the browser to this page.
But I prefer to have just the page without the .html.

When I remove the .html from the link the live server gives an error: Cannot GET /page1
But when I deploy my site on Netlify it does, however, find the page, but this breaks the development process for me.

How can I fix the live server so it also gets sent to the correct page?

Thank you in advance,
Timo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common server behaviour. The server tries to find a file or folder name `page1` but doesn't find it. Nothing wrong with live server. I guess Netlify is the one doing extra magic.

However if you want to remove the .html in page1 you could create a folder name page1 and put inside a index.html with the content. This way the server will find the folder named page1 and return the index.html. This will also work with live server and any standard server.

This is how your folder structure could look like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining, this makes sense and is the best solution. I've had to redo most of the imports (../) but it now works for both in netlify and with live server development!

Answer (score 1):

Cannot GET /source/gfdfghdgh/A/1&2.html

This is the error I get because of the '&' symbol.

Make sure your file name is browser friendly.

Answer (score 0):

```
      VS CODE LIVE SERVER CANNOT GET ERROR MESSAGE
```

Restart VSCode
Sometimes the best you can do is start VSCode from scratch. First, save all of your work. Then close VSCode, which will also stop all of the extensions you've installed. Then, reopen VSCode and try again – go to the HTML file you want to view, right-click## Heading ##, and select "Open with Live Server".

Comment: IF YOU FOUND THIS HELPFUL ,PLEASE VOTE FOR ME

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this didn't work. I think it's a problem with the live server not  finding the correct files or something, and not a vscode problem.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the ':5500' from the URl and it started working.

Changed from : http://127.0.0.1:5500/chat_system/dashboard.php

to : http://127.0.0.1/chat_system/dashboard.php

Comment: it is an URL, not URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). The port is not necessarily wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this helps but if your file has a symbol, that may cause the "cannot get error" just as DoubleDipper answered.
For example, I changed my code from 'Challenge#4' to 'Challenge4' and it worked